# Why can't I import ApplicationContext in Spring-5.0.0.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext, spring-framework-beans

I was trying to follow [this](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=spring-fundamentals&author=bryan-hansen&name=spring-m3-xml-config&clip=16&mode=live) tutorial on PluralSight to learn Spring. The tutorial is based on spring 4.3.2 while I wanted to learn it on 5.0.0. I imported the spring dependency using mvn:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

All the dependencies were imported fine. I created my `applicationContext.xml` and configured the beans. Now I am having issue importing `ApplicationContext`.

```
ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

The above line of code says couldn't resolve `ApplicationContext` and `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`.

I tried to find out if these classes have been changed in favour of any other class but I didn't found any such info on Spring website.

Am I missing on something or Is there any change in the way of using Spring after 5.0.0

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.saurabh</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Spring</name>
  <description>My first attempt at learning spring from Pluralsight</description>

  <!--  the stuff above this was generated automatically while I wrote all that is below -->
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Is it on compile time and have you checked whether the dependencies are downloaded or not

Comment: The org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext is in spring-context-X.X.X.RELEASE.jar. Do you have that jar on CLASSPATH?

Comment: Yes. I can see all the spring jars in my build path.

Comment: Since it is a maven project can you post your full `pom.xml`? Moreover did you try to `mvn clean compile`?

Comment: Clean your local repository (`mvn dependency:purge-local-repository`)and re-download the dependencies (`mvn package`).

Answer (score 0):

Please get all your dependencies from here:
[Spring Maven Dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework)

Looks like you are using correct dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Try to do `mvn clean install`